# vuetify button/icon at the end of the heading

Tags: javascript, css, button, icons, vuetify.js

I would like to have a little info button/icon next to my heading. The issue is it showing at the end of the first row while I would like to have it at the end of the whole heading.

````
"This is an example (info icon)
heading" //this is how it currently looks 

"This is an example
heading" (info icon) //this is how it should look

I'm using vuetify

```
               <div style="display:flex;">
                <p >{{ heading }}</p>
                 <div v-if="help">
                  <v-menu
                  offset-x
                  min-width="220"
                  rounded="lg"
                  >
                  <template v-slot:activator="{on }">
                  <v-btn v-on="on" icon class="mt-n2" >
                     <v-icon  color="black" style="transform: rotate(180deg);">mdi-alert-circle-outline</v-icon>
                  </v-btn>
                  </template>
                </v-menu>
               </div>
             </div>
````

Answer (score 0):

First of all use
`<v-icon  color="black">mdi-information-outline</v-icon>`
instead of
`<v-icon  color="black" style="transform: rotate(180deg);">mdi-alert-circle-outline</v-icon>`

Secondly I always use `justify-space-between` to get this result but Vuetify.js always suggests useing a `<v-spacer>`

With that out of the way I came up with this:

```
<v-card-title>
  {{ heading }}
  <v-spacer></v-spacer> <--- Place a spacer to separate your item
  <v-menu offset-y min-width="220" v-if="help">
    <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
      <v-btn v-on="on" icon small class="mt-n2">
        <v-icon>mdi-information-outline</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
    </template>
    <v-card>
      <v-card-text> Some helpful text </v-card-text>
    </v-card>
  </v-menu>
</v-card-title>
```

#### Result:

*In the image below I'm using the class `justify-space-between` without a spacer which results into a similar result*

[image: result when using code above]